# А используете ли вы вендорные префиксы для верстки?

Tags: css3, html, javascript, вёрстка, css

Как лучше: прописывать вручную для каждого браузера или к примеру использовать скрипты LESS       или PrefixFree? Я начинающий, так хотелось бы ваших советов услышать

Comment: Да, на работе используем [SASS][1] с его `@include`, если префикс больше не нужен, то просто убираете его из него.

  [1]: http://sass-lang.com/

Comment: include получилась ссылка на чувака с хешкода)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использование префиксов напрямую зависит от требований по поддержки браузеров и платформ. Если вы используете препроцессоры, то используйте их возможности (миксины и т.д. ), иначе используйте решения типа PrefixFree.

Answer (score 2):

Использую [Stylus](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/) и библиотечку [nib](http://visionmedia.github.io/nib/) для него, которая преобразовывает обычные css свойства в свойства с вендорными префиксами.
А еще ребята из Яндекса написали для Stylus библиотеку if-ie, которая упрощает поддержку всеми любимого браузера, подробнее можно почитать на [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/company/yandex/blog/169415/).

От вендорных префиксов, на мой взгляд, еще рано отказываться, т.к. если на десктопе ситуация более-менее предсказуемая и почти все браузеры обновляются автоматически, то вот на планшетах/смартфонах все далеко не так хорошо, поскольку хватает устаревших устройств, с уже устаревшим ПО, которое понимает только свойства с префиксами ;-)

Answer (score 1):

А я использую LESS, где использую миксины и примиси для вендорных префиксов.

Answer (score 0):

Ведущие собаководы рекомендуют использовать [автопрефиксер](http://habrahabr.ru/company/evilmartians/blog/176909/)